# QML - TableView - Access TableViewColumn property inside headerDelegate

Tags: qt, qml, tableview

I have custom `headerDelegate` inside `TableView`. I need to access properties of `TableViewColumn` such as `resizable` property inside `headerDelegate`.

Is there any way to access this property inside `headerDelegate`?

Is it possible to access user defined properties in `TableViewColumn` inside `headerDelegate`?

For example can I create a user defined property called `enableSorting` inside `TableViewColumn` and access it inside `headerDelegate` in order to hide or show `sortingIndicator`?

**UPDATE**

```
TableView{

 TableViewColumn{
    property bool sortingEnabled: false
    resizable: false
}

 headerDelegate: Rectangle {
   color: styleData.resizable?"red":"blue"
   border.color:styleData.sortingEnabled?"red":"blue"
 }

}
```

Here `styleData.resizable` & `styleData.sortingEnabled` are imaginary. I would like to get something like that.

Comment: please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have added a minimal example. But it is not reproducible.

Comment: I found an answer. It is super useful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of `TableView`, to access a column we can use

`getColumn(index)` method

```
TableView{

 TableViewColumn{
    property bool sortingEnabled: false
    resizable: false
}

 headerDelegate: Rectangle {
   color: getColumn(styleData.column).resizable?"red":"blue"
   border.color:getColumn(styleData.column).sortingEnabled?"red":"blue"

 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to set the TableView id property. You will be able to access it from the entire file scope in all the way you want.

```
TableView{
    id: myTableView
    headerDelegate: Rectangle {
       color: myTableView.whatever // Change whatever by any property of myTableView
    }
}
```

Important note : Setting the delegate id and accessing the other way around will not work because it is not instanciated right at the reading of the qml interpreter, plus it probably would target several instances of delegate items.